# Are Javascript generator and Clojure lazy-seq conceptually same

Tags: javascript, clojure, lazy-evaluation

Is the objective of Javascript generator function and Clojure lazy-seq function conceptually same, i.e. returning lazily evaluating list of values from function? Or are there some different use cases for each of these? Does Clojure use familiar mechanism to actually implement the lazy-seq?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript generators are mutable. Clojure lazy sequences are not.

Clojure has a dedicated mechanism for lazy sequences. to create one, you call the `lazy-sequence` macro. This wraps its body-form as a parameterless Clojure function (object implementing `clojure.lang.Ifn`) inside a `clojure.Lang.LazySeq` object that essentially memoizes the sequence protocol.